# How to show only number of current virtual desktop in taskbar? (KDE Plasma)

Tags: kde, taskbar, plasma-5, virtualdesktop

i dont want to switch desktops by taskbar (i do it by keyboard), but i want to see which desktop is active.
so i just want to see the number of *active* virtual desktop, not of all desktops.

is there any way?

Comment: That is indeed how the tiling window manager i3 handles this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the default distribution.

but when adding a new widget, you can click "Get new Widgets" and download the "SimplePager" widget.

and it does exactly what you asked.
Thanks for the suggestion, I am adopting it myself from now on.

Comment: works fine :) thx!